# Javascript regular expression: Want to exclude function words in all caps

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression to parse google script formula to get precedents

```
([A-z]{2,}!)?:?\$?[A-Z]\$?[A-Z]?(\$?[1-9]\$?[0-9]?)?
```

I needed to make the numbers optional to cater to ranges that are entire columns- see image. Because the numbers are optional I am also matching items that are functions -all caps words- that I want to exclude. I suppose I could do this after the fact but I would like to modify the regex to exclude them. How do I do that?

Example:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AA16,Account_List_S!$AA:$AC,3,0),0)
IFERROR(IF(AD3=1,INDEX(CapEx!$AB$15:$AE$15,1,YEAR(AD$13)-
YEAR($Z$13)-1)*IF(Import_CapEx!AD$15>=0,Import_CapEx!AD$15,0),0),0)";
```

The words I want to match refer to cells with an optional sheet name, and optional `$` before the row or column identifier. They can be ranges or single cells.

Examples of words I want to match:

```
$AA16
$AB$15
AD$15
$Z$13
Account_List_S!$AA:$AC
CapEx!$AB$15:$AE$15
Import_CapEx!AD$15
```

The words I want to exclude are the functions:

```
IFERROR
VLOOKUP
IF
YEAR
```

[image: image shows results]

Comment: Do you only want to match two capital letters when preceded by `$` and not followed by a number?

Comment: Just as a side note, you may think that `[A-z]` behaves the same as `[A-Za-z]`, but it actually doesn't, as the former matches additional characters: `[\]^_` plus backtick. See https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm and https://regex101.com/r/OMUcxA/1.

Comment: Thanks for question. I need to handle both cases. $ is optional

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit about what is your desired output? Do you also want to match e.g. `$AB$15` and `AD$15`?

Comment: Yes- I want to match $AB$15, AD$15. To be explicit I want the green items in the image to match except for the following : IFERROR  VLOOKUP  IF  YEAR

Comment: What is your real goal? Google probably has an API for that. To match, but not capture, surround expression like `(?:match_but_dont_remember)`. Of course, you would have to know how to walk the resulting Array of `String.match()`. We don't see any of that code, by the way.

Comment: You don't say what a "precedent" is or "ranges that are entire columns." It's unclear what you're asking to match, you're just giving examples of random parts of the image without explaining what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
/[\(,+\-\*/><=]((\w+!)?\$?[A-Z]{1,2}(\$?[\d]{0,3})?(:\$?[A-Z]{1,2}(\$?\d{0,3})?)?(?=[\),+\-\*/><=]))/g
```

While a little long, this has the advantage that it will reject these when found in the formula:

- Anything that has [A-Z] and [0-9] but not a column, e.g. `ZIP50210`
- Anything that has [A-Z] and [0-9] but in the wrong order, e.g. `25E`
- Any variables like `"AR"` or `'JOHN'`
- Any constants in the formula like `TRUE`, `FALSE` or other argument values

**Explanation:**

> `[\(,+\-\*/><=]`  look for starting literal `(` or `,` or operands like `+,-,/,*,>,<,=`. We expect column identifiers to start with these characters.
>
> `(`  now we start our matching group
>
> `(\w+!)?` allow for optional sheet names like `'Account_List_S!'`
>
> `\$?[A-Z]{1,2}(\$?[\d]{0,3})?` will match columns like `A` or `$B1` or `$AB$12` or `AB123`
>
> `(:\$?[A-Z_$]{1,2}(\$?[\d]{0,3}))?` adds optional match for a range of columns, e.g. trailing `:DD` or `:$C1` or `:AC$1` or `:AC123` or some such
>
> `(?=[,\)=:><])` lookahead for ending literal `)` or `,` or operands like `+,-,/,*,>,<,=`. We expect column identifiers to end with these characters.
>
> `)` close matching group
>
> `g` global match (more than one instance)

**Demo:**

```js
let regex =     /[\(,+\-\*/><=]((\w+!)?\$?[A-Z]{1,2}(\$?[\d]{0,3})?(:\$?[A-Z]{1,2}(\$?\d{0,3})?)?(?=[\),+\-\*/><=]))/g;

let str = '=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AA16,Account_List_S!$AA:$AC,3,0),0)IFERROR(IF(AD3=1,INDEX(CapEx!$AB$15:$AE$15,1,YEAR(AD$13)-YEAR($Z$13)-1)*IF(Import_CapEx!AD$15>=0,Import_CapEx!AD$15,0),0),0)";';

let arr = []

while(match = regex.exec(str)) {
    arr.push(match[1]); //we only want the first matching group
}

console.log(arr);
/*
    [ '$AA16',
    'Account_List_S!$AA:$AC',
    'AD3',
    'CapEx!$AB$15:$AE$15',
    'AD$13',
    '$Z$13',
    'Import_CapEx!AD$15',
    'Import_CapEx!AD$15' ] */
```

Comment: Thank you. This almost worked for me but it included some unwanted characters  such as , and (

Comment: You need to use the second element in the match array, i.e. match[1], not match[0]. See the demo example.

Comment: Doesn't work on this text whether  match[0] or match[1] Here is my google app script code `function testB(){
  var thisFormula="Calc_Named_HC!AE$32:AE$103)-";
  getPrecedentsB(thisFormula);
}
function getPrecedentsB(largeFormula){
  
Logger.clear();


var text=largeFormula ;
Logger.log(text); 
Logger.log("***********************************************************");   

var exp =/(?!\b[A-Z]{3,}\b|\bIF\b)(\b[A-z]{2,}!)?(:?\$?\b[A-Z]\$?[A-Z](\$?\d\$?\d?)?){1,2}\b/gm;
var match;
while((match=exp.exec(text))) {
    Logger.log(match[0]);
   }
}`

Comment: Sorry don't know how to format code better input not being handled is (minus sign at end causes problem `Calc_Named_HC!AE$32:AE$103)-`

Comment: I believe the problem was because my original regex only specified 2 digits as I didn't think you'd have such a big spreadsheet, but I guess I was wrong. I've now increased it to 3 digits to accomodate the 103 in :AE$103 above.   If that still doesn't work, please show the full string where `Calc_Named_HC!AE$32:AE$103)-` is found so I can see the context.

Comment: @StevenGreenbaum I've also added more boundary characters that are expected right before and after a column name – e.g. operands like `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, `=`. Feel free to add more to the list as it suits.

Answer (score 0):

**First shot: filter out full upper case words**

This answer is not perfect yet, but using a negative look-ahead at the beginning of the expression can allow you to filter out `IF` and any sequence of 3+ upper case letters:

```
(?!\b[A-Z]{3,}\b|\bIF\b)(\b[A-z]{2,}!)?:?\$?\b[A-Z]\$?[A-Z]?(\$?[1-9]\$?[0-9]?)?\b
```

The `\b` in several places is to make sure the positive and negative matches go from the beginning of the letter sequence to the end.

The problem that remains is that it matches `Account_List_S!$AA:$AC` in two matches, `Account_List_S!$AA` and `:$AC`. So...

**Second shot: fix the positive matching part of the regex**

Here is a more complicated version that matches the ranges correctly:

EDIT: fixed to handle the examples given by OP in the comments.

```
(?!\b[A-Z]{3,}\b|\bIF\b)(\b[A-z]{2,}!)?\$?\b[A-Z]{1,3}(\$?[1-9]{1,3})?(:\$?[A-Z]{1,3}(\$?\d{1,3})?)?\b
```

With this version, `Account_List_S!$AA:$AC` is matched as a whole, as I believe you want, and so is `Calc_Named_HC!AE$32:AE$103` added in the comments below.

**Third shot: accepts some spurious patterns but easier to read**

If you are willing to accept matching a superfluous `:` before the first address, this simpler expression would work:

EDIT: fixed to handle the examples given in the comments.

```
(?!\b[A-Z]{3,}\b|\bIF\b)(\b[A-z]{2,}!)?(:?\$?\b[A-Z]{1,3}(\$?\d{1,3})?){1,2}\b
```

Note that I kept your `[A-z]` range as is, but `[A-Za-z_]` might be more appropriate, as pointed out by @sp00m in his comment.

Comment: spoke too soon it's spliting `Calc_Named_HC!AE$32:AE$103` it should be one match but it's splitting on the :

Comment: It works if the last $ is present `Calc_Named_HC!AE$32:$AE$103` but doesn't work if the last dollar is not present 'Calc_Named_HC!AE$32:$AE$1`Calc_Named_HC!AE$32:AE$103`

Comment: @StevenGreenbaum Fixed to handle your new examples.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a bad fit for a regular expression, but I cant pass up a good regex challenge.

My solution involves alot of conditional checks

`(\w+\!)?\$?[A-Z]{1,}(?:\d+)?(\:?\$\w+)*(?!\()\b`

**Breakdown**

```
(
  \w+\!        Words followed by an !
)?             which might exist.
\$?            A $ which might exist
[A-Z]{1,}      At least 1 capitalized letter maybe more
(?:                 
   \d+         A non capturing group of digits after our letters
)?             but they might not exist

(
  \:?          A : which might exist
  \$\w+        A $ followed by characters
)*             With none or many of them

(?!\()         All of this, ONLY IF we DONT have a ( after it
\b             All of this, ONLY IF we have a word break
```

The magic really happens at the end with the conditional breaks, without them you capture alot of other stuff.

---

**Sample**

```js
let text = `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AA165,Account_List_S!$AA:$AC,3,0),0)
IFERROR(IF(AD3=1,INDEX(CapEx!$AB$15:$AE$15,1,YEAR(AD$13)-
YEAR($Z$13)-1)*IF(Import_CapEx!AD$15>=0,Import_CapEx!AD$15,0),0),0)";`

let exp = /(\w+\!)?\$?[A-Z]{1,}(?:\d+)?(\:?\$\w+)*(?!\()\b/gm

let match;
while((match=exp.exec(text))) {
    console.log(match[0]);
}
```

Ouput:

```
$AA165
Account_List_S!$AA:$AC
AD3
CapEx!$AB$15:$AE$15
AD$13
$Z$13
Import_CapEx!AD$15
Import_CapEx!AD$15
```

---

Simple change to the expression making the $ after the : optional makes it work for your added use case

`(\w+\!)?\$?[A-Z]{1,}(?:\d+)?(\:?\$?\w+)*(?!\()\b`

```js
let text = `$X74,Calc_Named_HC!AE$32:AE$103)-Calc_General_HC!AE74";`
let exp = /(\w+\!)?\$?[A-Z]{1,}(?:\d+)?(\:?\$\w+)*(?!\()\b/gm
let match;
while((match=exp.exec(text))) {
    console.log(match[0]);
}
```

Comment: @ug_ I spoke too soon. with text of `$X74,Calc_Named_HC!AE$32:AE$103)-Calc_General_HC!AE74";` the `Calc_Named_HC!AE$32:AE$103` is not being extracted as one term, it is being split

Comment: Simple change to the expression makes it work, but realistically your example didn't include this and you didnt much in the way of a specific pattern to match. Its not the minus at the end, its the `$` which may or may not linger before a variable

Comment: @ug_  It works if the last $ is present `Calc_Named_HC!AE$32:$AE$103` but doesn't work if the last dollar is not present `Calc_Named_HC!AE$32:AE$103` the expression i am using is ` /(\w+\!)?\$?[A-Z]{1,}(?:\d+)?(\:?\$?\w+)*(?!\();\b/gm;`  It looks like the last $ in your regex is not optional. I added a ? after the $ but that didn't resolve the issue

Comment: @StevenGreenbaum that isnt the regex in my post. I dont have a trailing `;` at the end, also the one in your comment isnt quite valid. Have you tried the one in my post?

Comment: @ug_ You are correct. I had a syntax error in my expression  It does work if I make the last $ optional. I had an extra ; in the last regexp. All good now. The final expression is: ` var exp = /(\w+\!)?\$?[A-Z]{1,}(?:\d+)?(\:?\$?\w+)*(?!\()\b/gm`  thanks for your help.

Comment: @ug_ another issue from text  =If(Trigger_Hires!$AB60="$ Rev",0,0)    Rev is being extracted. This is undesired. Please advise. TIA